# ¿Como remplazo un carácter por otro en una cadena de texto al rebanarlo? / python

Tags: python

Hola estoy haciendo un programa que cumpla las siguientes instrucciones:

Se necesita una cadena de caracteres de 16 dígitos:

**4915110176928790**

Luego debe separar los 6 primeros números de la cadena:

[491511] | [0176928790]

Se va a fijar en el segundo grupo:

**[0176928790]**

Después, este grupo lo debe separar en modo (3-4-3), es decir:

**[017] [6928] [790]**

Eliminar el número central de cada parte y remplazarlo por una **"x"**:

**[0x7] [6xx8] [7x0]**

Por último,agregar la cadena con los 6 primeros números:
Resultado Final: *491511***0x76xx87x0**

Yo intente hacerlo pero solo logre separarlos en 3, 4, 3,  ya que las cadenas de texto rebanadas son inmutables.

```
def metodo(c1):
    c2_c1 = c1[6:len(c1)]
    c3 = c1[:6]
    c4_c1 = c2_c1[:3]
    c5_c1 = c2_c1[3:7]
    c6_c1 = c2_c1[7:10]
        
     
   print=(c4_c1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como las largos y posiciones son fijas, puedes simplemente cortar y pegar:

```
def fcn(cadena):
    return cadena[:7] + "x" + cadena[8:10] + "xx" + cadena[12:14] + "x" + cadena[-1]
```

Comprabación:

```
print(fcn("4915110176928790"))
```

produce

```
4915110x76xx87x0
```

Comment: Wow, es bastante simple muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Yo usaría otro tipo de aproximación, algo más general, usando una cadena de formato:

```py
def metodo(cadena, formato):
    def choose(c, a):
        return c if a == '_' else a

    return "".join(choose(c,a) for (c,a) in zip(cadena, formato))

print(metodo("4915110176928790", "_______x__xx__x_"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Partamos de la base que todas las cadenas son inmutables en python, no solo las slice. Ahora bien, como las posiciones a modificar son fijas plantearía de otra forma una posible solución:

```
cadena= "4915110176928790"
    
def metodo(cadena):
    #sc1= cadena[:6]
    #print(sc1)
    #sc2= cadena[6:9]
    #sc3=cadena[9:13]
    #sc4=cadena[13:]
    #todo lo comentado es por si necesitas mostrarlo, sino ni hace falta
    re1=list(cadena)
    for x in range(len(re1)):
        if x in (7,10,11,14):
            re1[x]="x"
    final = "".join(re1)    
    return final
          
    
print(metodo(cadena))
```

de una forma simple.
Saludos

Answer (score 1):

lo mejor que puedes hacer es el uso de **slices** para que puedas crear tus sub cadenas, creo que lo que tratas de hacer es esto:

```
def metodo(c1):
  c2=c1[:6]
  c3=c1[6:]
  c4=list(c3[:3])
  c5=list(c3[3:7])
  c6=list(c3[7:])
  print(c2, c3)

  # Estos if/else deben ir en una funcion aparte y hacer el llamado a la misma
  # pasando como parametro la cadena que deseas rellenar con "X"

  if int(len(c4)/2)==1:
    i=int(len(c4)/2)
    c4[i]="x"
  else:
    i=int(len(c4)/2)
    c4[i-1]=c4[i]="x"
  if int(len(c5)/2)==1:
    i=int(len(c5)/2)
    c5[i]="x"
  else:
    i=int(len(c5)/2)
    c5[i-1]=c5[i]="x"
  if int(len(c6)/2)==1:
    i=int(len(c6)/2)
    c6[i]="x"
  else:
    i=int(len(c6)/2)
    c6[i-1]=c6[i]="x"
  print(c4, c5, c6)
  
  # Esta concatenación tb la deberías hacer en otra función y pasar las cadenas
  # como parámetros de la función

  # concatenación simple
  c7=c2
  print(c7)

  # concatenación usando **.join() .map() method**
  c7+=''.join(map(str, c4))
  print(c7)

  # concatenación usando **list comprehension**
  c7+=''.join([str(elem) for elem in c5])
  print(c7)
  c7+=''.join([str(elem) for elem in c6])
  print(c7)

c='4915110176928790'
metodo(c)
```

Obviamente queda por mejorar el código de manera que no sean tan redundante, eso te lo dejo para ti.

Saludos.

Comment: Sería mejor que mejoraras el código tú mismo. Asi tan largo no se entiende tan bien.